# Statement to be notified of new Service Broker conversations on queue only

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

## Summary

I am looking for a statement or short TSQL script that will sleep wait for the next message NOT in a known conversation group so that a worker can be allocated to that conversation group and begin processing the messages in that group. In other words, to sleep until a new conversation is started. I am looking for a better method than polling as polling is inefficient and causes unnecessary latency.

## Background

I am designing a service that is available to database applications via the SQL Server Service broker. For reasons that are not important here, each instance of the target side service has a lot of internal state; each message needs to be routed to the correct process. The system needs to be able to handle requests from multiple clients concurrently. Multiple requests on one conversation from any given client are related to each other and processed serially.

## One conversation per worker process

Currently, each conversation initiated to the Target SB Service starts a dedicated worker process; the lifetime of that process and conversation are linked together. Most requests consist of the Initiator sending a message and immediately waiting for a response before continuing.

- Each Target worker gets its own dedicated `conversation_group_id` to identify its interactions on the queue.
- I use `RECEIVE` with the `WHERE conversation_group_id = @group` option in each worker process's message pump so that any given service instance only receives its own messages and does not conflict with other instances running on the same Service/Queue.
- When a worker initiates its own conversation, it will assign the new dialog to the existing conversation group with the `RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP` clause.
- If a worker encounters a fatal error, it uses `END CONVERSATION ... WITH ERROR ...` to terminate the session (and the process) with a system error message to the Initiator. The Initiator will propagate that error and close its end of the conversation.
- If the Initiator ends the conversation (including by error) the Target worker closes its end and exits.
- The dialog `LIFETIME` option is used to prevent a Target worker processes from being kept around for an excessive amount of time.

## Better notification method needed to trigger new worker process creation

The system works great for the individual worker processes. The problem I am having is in synchronizing the parent process that launches new workers in response to new conversations.

- `RECEIVE` is the only statement I know of that will block until a new message is available for processing on a queue with the `WAITFOR` clause. This is important to avoid polling.
- `RECEIVE` appears to have exactly two possible `WHERE` conditions to limit the messages selected: to filter to exactly one known conversation endpoint or one known conversation endpoint group.

The simplest solution would be to pass a `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` clause to the `WHERE` condition of `RECEIVE` that excludes conversation groups that already have a worker assigned. This does not appear to be supported by the syntax.

Using a direct `RECEIVE` without a `WHERE` can and will pick up messages meant for a specific worker that already exists; messages which cannot be handled by the parent process. Receiving the message into the wrong process presents new problems like the need to the message back with a `ROLLBACK` to undo the queue removal (potentially many times if it takes the worker a while to get to that message) and that method also increases the poison message counter unnecessarily.

The only solution I have at present is to do repeatedly `SELECT` `sys.conversation_endpoints` or the queue directly, once per second, looking for conversations that are in a new group without a worker. This introduces up to one extra second of latency and presumably has higher overhead than a simple blocking `RECEIVE`

Is there a better way to be notified of only NEW conversations to the Service or Queue?

Comment: You lost me. Are you using external activation, or is it about activation stored procedures? With the latter, there is no polling AFAIR.

Comment: It's not external activation or activated procedures. External clients calling into SQL Server on both sides.